# Django filter by datetime month__gte is not working

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using **Django 2.2**

I have a `created` field of **DateTime** type.

I'm using following command to filter the records which are greater than specific date

```
q.filter(created__year__gte=2020, created__month__gte=3, created__day__gte=1)
```

In my database there are records for March (3) month and more but not for February (2).

When above command is executed, it gives me queryset list of data greater than **March 1**. But when I use the following command

```
q.filter(created__year__gte=2020, created__month__gte=2, created__day__gte=28)
```

Where month is February (2), it is not giving any data and the queryset is blank.

Using `datetime` object gives error

```
received a naive datetime (2020-03-01 00:00:00) while time zone support is active
```

Why filter is not working with `gte` even when month is less than `3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was not with the **Django** setup, instead it was with the **MySQL** configuration due to missing timezone data.

Check this answer for how to resolve this error

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60844090/3719167

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to filter like this? In your case it is totally unnecessary. Just filter by date strictrly

```
q.filter(created__gte=datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1))
```

Comment: Because timezone support is enabled, using datetime object gives `naive-aware` error.

Comment: @AnujTBE then use django.utils.timezone

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
q.filter(created__date__gte=datetime.date(2020, 3, 1))
```

Regarding the filter, its working perfectly when month < 3, but if you specify that day > 28, then its already narrowing results set to only data that was crated between 29-31 day for every month, not only Feb. And most likely its not what you want.

Comment: This doesn't work with newly created objects. removing `date__` gives warning but works fine.