# Django TruncDate gives null

Tags: python, mysql, django, timezone

I'm using **Django 2.2**

I'm filtering records using Django query like

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

start_date = datetime.strptime('2020-02-01', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
end_date = datetime.strptime('2020-03-31', '%Y-%m-%d').date()

lead_list = LeadList.objects.all()

# Filter query
query = LeadListEntry.objects.filter(
    lead_list__in=lead_list
  )

# Filter by start date
query = query.filter(
    created__gte=start_date
  )

# Filter by end date
query = query.filter(
    created__lte=end_date
  )

# Annotate date
query = query.annotate(
     created_date=TruncDate('created')
   ).order_by(
     'created_date'
   ).values('created_date').annotate(
     **{'total': Count('created')}
   )
```

The SQL query generated is

```
SELECT 
    DATE(CONVERT_TZ(`lead_generation_leadlistentry`.`created`, 'UTC', 'UTC')) AS `created_date`, 
    COUNT(`lead_generation_leadlistentry`.`created`) AS `total`
FROM `lead_generation_leadlistentry` 
WHERE (
    `lead_generation_leadlistentry`.`lead_list_id` IN (
        SELECT 
            U0.`id` FROM `lead_generation_leadlist` U0 
        WHERE 
            U0.`deleted` IS NULL
    )
    AND `lead_generation_leadlistentry`.`created` >= '2020-02-01 00:00:00' 
    AND `lead_generation_leadlistentry`.`created` <= '2020-03-31 00:00:00'
)
GROUP BY DATE(CONVERT_TZ(`lead_generation_leadlistentry`.`created`, 'UTC', 'UTC'))
ORDER BY `created_date` ASC
```

This is behaving different on local and staging server

**Local Development server**

```
+--------------+-------+
| created_date | total |
| ------------ | ----- |
| 2020-02-25   | 15    |
| 2020-02-27   | 10    |
+--------------+-------+
```

**Staging server**

```
+--------------+-------+
| created_date | total |
| ------------ | ----- |
| null         | 15    |
+--------------+-------+
```

The date column is `null`

**NOTE**: Django has timezone enabled by `USE_TZ=True`

**LeadListEntry** model

```
class LeadListEntry(models.Model):
    lead_list = models.ForeignKey(LeadList, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lead_list_entry')
    data = models.TextField(help_text='Lead List entry data. (JSON data)', blank=False)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Please share your model fields

Comment: Please check I have added the model fields. I don't think it is related to the model field, instead it should be error in the database because running same SQL script works in local database but not in staging database.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the solution for the users getting the same error

The error was not with the **Django**, instead it was with the **MySQL** database setup.

The date field returns `null` because `CONVERT_TZ` does not work. This can be due to no timezone data in the MySQL database.

To import the timezone data, execute following command

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

After importing, restart the mysql server.

Comment: I wish could upvote your answer 100 times. Saved my sanity. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem of different results from local to staging may happen because of different DateTime of the machine, I got this before when I was developing on windows but the staging was ubuntu, it turned out `strptime()` date parameters were different and kept showing errors.

For date filtering and as your code sample you don't have to create a date object, just a correct string date format will be enough

```
start_date = '2020-02-01'
end_date = '2020-03-31'
```

Then go as normal.

I would like to do something like this,

```
# As you only need LeadList id's for foreginkey filtering, this is more optimized
lead_list = LeadList.objects.all().values_list('id')

# Filter query
query = LeadListEntry.objects.filter(
    lead_list__in=lead_list, created__date__gte = start_date, created__date__lte=end_date
  )
```

and to group by date

```
query = query.values('created__date').annotate(count=Count('created__date')).order_by('created__date')
```

Comment: But the above SQL script when executed in workbench, gives the same result as given in the question. Can't this be a MySQL server issue?

Comment: Your solution still gives `<LeadListEntryQuerySet [{'created__date': None, 'count': 7}]>`. `created__date` is null.